# Offline maps in an Android app

Tags: android, maps, offline

I'm developing this tourist app and I would like to have an **offline** map of one exact city integrated in it (an activity). I'd like to note that I'm completely new both to java and to android so it's a really hard task for me. I wanted to ask - are there any tutorials or some basic information for newbies? Or maybe some open source projects that I could copy the code from? I've heard about osmdroid but I don't know how to use it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simonas, Since you are apparently new, make sure to read the Android docs thoroughly. Starting with a good structure will save you endless hours in the future. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely use OSM droid. it supports offline map storing. its usage is completely the same as the google's mapView. so any tutorial for the mapview would work for OSM droid also with slight modifications.

and you need to learn how to program android apps in order to actually program them... just start off with some simple tutorials for android and be persistant. learning to code android apps wont happen overnight..